# Why making ISBNs primary keys of the book table a poor choice?

Tags: primary-key

Why making ISBNs primary keys of the book table a poor choice? I don't quite get what Carter have explained in lecture 1 - Relating, CS50 SQL. Although ISBNs are memory consuming, but they are worth being primary keys because they are unique for each book.

Comment: Did you ask Carter (whoever that is)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -3):

Not all books have ISBNs. ISBN was invented in 1970s.